# Drag-and-drop in Notepad++: file too large

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to open a file txt in Notepad++, by drag-and-drop the file in the Notepad++ window. File size is about 276 MB. Notepad++ return the error:

```
File too large
```

If i open the same file by `right click -> open in Notepad++` the file is opened successfully.

Notepad++ version 7.5.9 64-bit, no extensions installed.

Why this happen? What is the difference between opening a file in Notepad++ by drag-and-drop and by `right click -> open in Notepad++` ?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a file of 283 MB - both methods work equally well. This might be caused by an extension?

Comment: What version of Notepad++? (**? > Debug Info > Copy debug info into clipboard**)  How much system memory was available when you tried the drag-and-drop; how much system memory was available when you RClick from Explorer?  Is it 100% repeatable that drag-and-drop fails and RClick succeeds? (Note the hidden guess in my question: system memory/resources changed between the two attempts, and it was that, not drag-vs-rclick, that caused the fail/success of loading the file)

Comment: @PeterCJ tried 2 times by drag-and-drop (both "too large"), and then rclick (sucessfully opened). Anycase i take your hidden guess as possible. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the version.  I was also hoping for the 32-bit vs 64-bit; sometimes 32-bit is more restricted in file size... But really, it's more system memory/resources that cause the problem

Comment: With 32bit 7.5.8 portable, I was able to drag open 512Mb, or 3 128Mb; tried a fourth 128Mb, or used File-Open or RClick, it wouldn't open the fourth: my 32bit limit was ~512Mb.  With 64-bit 7.5.9 portable, run with `-noPlugin`, I could not open exactly 2Gb file at all (the per-file limit is 2Gb), but I could open two 1.5Gb files plus a 1Gb file and three 512Mb files.  I cannot replicate your problem with your conditions.  Again, I am guessing it's system/memory issues, not NPP itself.  (I was at about 7.5G used of 8Gb physical, plenty of paged)